# Angular can't access child routes when using forChild

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-module

Hei, am currently working on an angular app, and facing an issue with `loadChildren` in the router. I posted a question earlier with a similar issue, but now is i hav ran all tests possible as well as moving the routing part of each module into separate modules. I can reach top level routes such as `auth` but not any of its children such as `auth/login`. My routing modules is s following:

#### app.router

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: 'app/main/main.module#MainModule',
    canActivate: [OauthGuard]
  }, {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: 'app/authentication/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule',
  }, {
   path: '**',
   component: PageNotFoundComponent,
   pathMatch: 'full'
   }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true}) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRouterModule {}
```

#### authentication.router

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthenticationComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: RegisterComponent,
        outlet: 'auth'
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
        outlet: 'auth'
      }
    ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AuthenticationRouterModule {}
```

When trying to navigate to `auth/login` i get the `PageNotFoundComponent` every time. I have enabled trace route and the path is not recognized, so i logged the routes registered getting following output:

```
Routes:  [
  {
    "path": "",
    "outlet": "app",
    "pathMatch": "full",
    "canActivate": [
      null
    ]
  },
  {
    "path": "auth",
    "loadChildren": "app/authentication/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule"
  },
  {
    "path": "**",
    "outlet": "app"
  }
]
```

So my routes never gets registered, even after carefully using `forRoot` and `forChild` on the different modules. I have read pretty much everything i can find on the topic, but in the the end pointing back to using the code i already have. I'm posting my ng version in case it's a bug or problem with this version.

> #### My current setup
>
> - @angular/cli: 1.1.1
> - node: 6.10.3
> - os: win32 x64
> - @angular/animations: 4.1.3
> - @angular/common: 4.1.3
> - @angular/compiler: 4.1.3
> - @angular/core: 4.1.3
> - @angular/forms: 4.1.3
> - @angular/http: 4.1.3
> - @angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.6
> - @angular/platform-browser: 4.1.3
> - @angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.3
> - @angular/platform-server: 4.1.3
> - @angular/router: 4.1.3
> - @angular/cli: 1.1.1
> - @angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.3
> - @ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
> - @ngtools/webpack: 1.4.1

Anyone had a similar problem, or knows how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By defining:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthenticationComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: RegisterComponent,
        outlet: 'auth'
      },
      {
        path: 'auth/login',
        component: LoginComponent,
        outlet: 'auth'
      }
    ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AuthenticationRouterModule {}
```

To render the `LoginComponent`, you would have to navigate to `root/auth/auth/login`. As soon as you enter the path `auth` in the routes used in the `forRoot` method, the path used to load the children will be added to them as **prefix**.

To achieve what you want, you need to define the following routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthenticationComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: RegisterComponent,
        outlet: 'auth'
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
        outlet: 'auth'
      }
    ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AuthenticationRouterModule {}
```

EDIT:

After taking a look at the documentation for [named outlets](https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets), to navigate to LoginComponent you need the following path:

```
root/auth(auth:login)
```

This is because the component will be rendered by a named outlet. For further info take a closer look to the docs.

Comment: Sorry forgot to remove the `auth` there, just did som testing to check the path, the code is actually equal to your suggestion. Updating now

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Removed outlet names after reading through the docs, just realized that it is possible to have more unnamed outlets as long as they belong to different scopes. This finally resolved my issue, thanks a lot @Jota.Teledo